# Nested Full height tableviews, both with multiple and variable height cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Problem example: https://github.com/hecode/problem-example
using method 3 mentioned below
sorry for the rushed code.

the view is very complex but i will try to explain as much as i can.
the view looks something like this:

```
******full height parent table**************
    ******parent cell*************************
       * static content
       * variable height label
       *** full height inner tableview*****
          *** inner cell *****
          * static content
          * variable height label
          ********************
       ************************************
   *****************************************
********************************************
```

both cells are variable height using:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and both tableviews are full height. for the parent i am using an observer on contentsize and updating it there which is working correctly.

my current problem is that the inner cell's tableview, its contentsize doesn't return the correct contentsize.

i tried:

1.using an observer on contentsize and changing the tableview's height constraint to the new value
2.changing the tableview's height constraint in overriden layoutSubviews with contentsize
3.changing the tableview's height constraint in overriden willDisplay with contentsize in the last cell and making the tableview's bottom constraint 750 instead of 1000, if it's 1000 then clipping happens

the first two methods result in clipping in most cases, and sometimes extra variable size space at the bottom. 
the third methods has extra variable size space.

in the third method i tried printing the cell frame heights and compare them with the values in the xcode uidebugger and found that they are different.

btw the inner cell gets the data from the parent table and is the delegate and data source for the inner tableview

can someone give me any ideas? is there a way to get actual content size for the inner tableview to set the table's height constraint to it?

removing height constraint and using a bottom constraint to parent view results in clipping and also the innertableview is supposed to visible sometimes not all of the time so the height constraint is used to set it to 0 for the times it isn't needed.

i am using ios10.3, swift 3

Comment: *"full height inner tableview"* ... is that a table view with variable number of rows? Or just one row (cell) with "static content and a variable height label"?

Comment: table view with variable number of rows, edited title to clearify

Comment: Can you create a minimal example demonstrating what you are doing?

Comment: sorry for the messy code since i am in hurry. https://github.com/hecode/problem-example

Comment: You should take a look at `systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompresedSize)`. That can return the "best fit" size for a view - including its subviews - based on satisfying constraints. So, in the last `willDisplay cell:` in your `ParentTableViewCell`, instead of getting the height from `tableView.contentSize.height` try getting the height from `self.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height`. Note that you'll need to apply a width constraint, but that could be a good direction to go. Otherwise *(next comment) ...*

Comment: While using a tableview with reusable cells is convenient, you might be better off making your "inner table" a `UIStackView` instead, and just `addArrangedSubview()` with custom views that *look* like cells.

Comment: systemLayoutSizeFitting didn't work, and wouldn't i need to know the stack's height and change it's constraint as well? i tried that with tableview and uiview(by adding subviews similar to stackview), and both don't work correctly. ended up changing the design. but for future reference, what would be the best practice to realize such design?

Comment: It's a bit tough to say... Your layout appears to be: tables in table rows in a scroll view. In general, tables are *designed* to scroll multiple rows, so it's not at all clear why you're putting a tableview inside a scrollview (and then changing its "fixed height") to begin with. Also, it's not clear why you don't use Sections to show "sub-tables", or even just different cell types. Apple has done a good job of providing auto-layout for auto-sizing cells... best bet is to learn how to use that.

Comment: in the actual app the parent table is in a scrollview because there is a part on top of it that isn't part of the table, and i am using multiple sections for different type of cells, a cell in the section is basically the parent cell which is for example a post and comments on the post in a section. after thinking, in the future the top part should be a section, and the table should take the whole view and scrollable instead of full height in a scrollview, but now how would you do posts and their comments? what i did here was make a post cell and add a tableview to it for its comments

Comment: Too vague to say... Might a post have 250 comments? Or a comment that is 200 lines long? If so, your current UI needs some changes. If it will never be more than a few short comments, then a stack view with custom views (instead of tableviewcells) might be best - stack views work great with auto-layout / auto-sizing cells.

Comment: i see. i guess just showing number of comments and opening a new view really is best for this case.